# jQuery Spin plugin does nothing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using the [jQuery Spin Plugin](https://github.com/ksylvest/jquery-spin) to show a spinner during an ajax call. I have everything set up like in the example, but nothing happens when I try to initialize the spinner.

```
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="javascripts/jquery.spin.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="stylesheets/jquery.spin.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
    <div id="spinner" data-spin></div>
    <select id="mySelect">...</select>
    <select id="code">...</select>
    <div id="person"></div>
</body>

$(function() {
$(document)
    .ajaxStart(function() {
        $("#spinner").spin("show");

    })
    .ajaxStop(function() {
        $("#spinner").spin("hide");
    });

$("#mySelect").change(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "ajax-refresh",
        data: {
            code: $("#code option:selected").val(),
        },
        success: function(resp) {
            $("#person").html(resp);
        }
    });
});
});
```

Comment: Why is your script tag in your header? Try moving it after `body`. Also, per the docs, it looks like you might need to call `.spin()` to initialize the plugin? It's not explicitly said on their docs but it may be the cause, usually plugins do have some sort of init method that's needed.

Answer (score 0):

The instructions shown in the referenced link includes these commands.
[image]

It appears that the .spin function may need to be called first without arguments before making subsequent calls with 'show' and 'hide'.

Comment: Nothing on their documentation explicitly says you need to call it first, but I agree the OP should try it.

Comment: I did try this. I should have mentioned that in my question.

Comment: I suggest adding a JavaScript "alert" call after each .spin function call just to make sure that that code is being executed.